# How is the recorded sound of a galloping horse so much different from a trot or a canter?

Tags: audio-recording, sound-effects, sound, field, effect

I recently started getting interested in equestrianism after going on my first-ever horse-drawn carriage ride for the winter holiday season. In that ride, the horse was doing a characteristic trot and even at one point slowed down to a walk. The hooves made a clop-clop-clop sound on the concrete pavement as it pulled the carriage.

However, I've been curious to hear what a galloping horse sounded like, since I imagined it would make a completely different sound when all four of its legs left the ground and then came back down in random order. But after listening to some samples on YouTube, I was disappointed to find that they did not correspond to the sound that hooves made when hitting concrete. Instead, it sounded as though they were galloping on wooden boards or something.

Also, this video seems to be a misnumer, as it apparently describes a horse in cantering or trotting strides, but it definitely sounds more like a gallop!

This one, a horse galloping on grass, actually sounds more realistic, as the horse's hooves seems to be muffled by the grass beneath.

This one, a cantering horse, also seems more realistic in comparison to the first one.

And finally, I remember having this Yamaha piano keyboard many years ago, a PSR192. I forgot which number it was, there was a sound effect of a horse cantering on concrete that had that typical cop-clop-cop sound.

So, I'm curious to know exactly how these sounds are recorded, and whether they are actualy realistic. I'm hoping to learn how to ride a horse in varying strides on different surfaces, so that I can record them myself.

Comment: It's not 'socio-politically acceptable' to gallop horses on hard roads. They slip &/or break ankles. I've seen it done on set & I'm not quite sure how they got away with it. Indiana Jones Dial of Destiny at 43:50 there's an entire horse chase scene on hard road. The soundtrack doesn't sound like it did on set; it sounds like they overdubbed softer terrain. On the day it sounded like someone throwing anvils at the road. Ironically, for 'health & safety' the Harley motorbike was electric not petrol… but the horse had to run on those streets time after time.

Comment: My try searching for actual videos of horses that also have sound instead of searching for horse sound effects. Then you’ll be able to see what kind of gait the horse is using in the video and hear how it sounds.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're not interested in the old Hollywood method of making foley horses, used for decades of cowboy movies - banging coconut shells into various substrates in a box - then you have to do it the same way as you record anything else…

You either park a mic in a fixed position on the ground & run the horse past it, or you hang a mic off the horse as you run.
For either, I'd choose an omni - personally, a DPA 4006 'pencil mic' or a 4060 'lav mic'. Neither suffer from body/handling noise, though the 4006 is likely to suffer more from wind than the 4060 unless it's in a dead cat [wind shield].